# nao bringup error

Tags: ros, naoqi, ros-indigo, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm just getting started with a nao, and i'm getting an error when I try and run the bringup launch. I've been following the nao tutorials for ros and the install went fine. When I got to the [getting started](http://wiki.ros.org/nao/Tutorials/Getting-Started) tutorial the code, the following line produces an error :

```
roslaunch nao_bringup nao_full.launch
```

error:

```
[I] 6927 qimessaging.transportserver: TransportServer will listen on: tcp://192.168.1.126:39105
[W] 7063 qimessaging.transportsocket: resolve: Host not found (authoritative)
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1436292007.715455] Could not create Proxy to "ALVideoDevice". 
Exception message:
    ALBroker::createBroker
    Cannot connect to tcp://<192.168.1.127>:9559
[INFO] [WallTime: 1436292007.751839] Stopping naoqi_camera
[INFO] [WallTime: 1436292007.752147] naoqi_camera stopped
[I] 6911 qimessaging.session: Session listener created on tcp://0.0.0.0:0
[I] 6911 qimessaging.transportserver: TransportServer will listen on: tcp://127.0.0.1:42822
[I] 6911 qimessaging.transportserver: TransportServer will listen on: tcp://192.168.1.126:42822
[W] 7076 qimessaging.transportsocket: resolve: Host not found (authoritative)
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1436292007.801604] Could not create Proxy to "ALVideoDevice". 
Exception message:
    ALBroker::createBroker
    Cannot connect to tcp://<192.168.1.127>:9559
[INFO] [WallTime: 1436292007.879432] Stopping naoqi_camera
[INFO] [WallTime: 1436292007.880013] naoqi_camera stopped
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

This is with roscore running. I've also tried this with and without running naoqi first.
Both my computer and the nao are on the same network.
In the Choregraphe program, the nao is also not visible.

EDIT JULY 6, 2015

I got Choregraphe to connect to my Nao by downloading a different version, version 1.14.5 instead of the latest build.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213071/nao-bringup-error/) by [jlzizmor](https://answers.ros.org/users/22862/jlzizmor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-07-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For me, this seems as if you try to connect to the wrong IP.
Can you verify that your NAO_IP is set to the correct IP of your robot?
when in doubt, start your program like this:

```
NAO_IP=<ip_of_your_robot> roslaunch nao_bringup nao_full.launch
```

Then further, please check that naoqi is running successfully on your robot. If not, the bridge can't connect to it. You can check also by opening choregraphe and see if the camera is working fine.

---

Originally posted by [Karsten](https://answers.ros.org/users/8211/karsten/) with karma: 643 on 2015-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0